# Comparing negative numbers in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I have a problem using comparison operator "<" in pine script. If i want for example all values under 5 including those negative under 0, like -1, -2, -5, then  "condition < 5" returns only positive numbers till zero. How can i include negative numbers in this condition?

Comment: Please show us your code. It shouldn't be an issue as @PineCoders-LucF showed you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-1 < 5` evaluates to "true".

```
//@version=4
study("")
bgcolor(-1 < 5 ? color.green : na)
```

[image]

Comment: omg. i must have been coding too much without rest. thanks on clarification!